# First paragraph indentation with ragged2e and \RaggedRightParindent set

Tags: indentation, ragged2e

I am using the `ragged2e` package for my `raggedright` text and have set `\RaggedRightParindent` to 2em, as I want my paragraphs indented. But now, the *very* first paragraph in the document (following `\maketitle` is also indented. My original question was why the first graf in a new section is indented, though, as the first commenter pointed out and as the MWE shows, the first graf in a new section is *not* indented. So my question is now why the very first paragraph is not indented.

Is there anyway to have `ragged2e` set `\RaggedRightParindent` for the very first paragraph of a document to return to flush left?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,article,oneside]{memoir}

%% packages
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{datetime} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[footnotesep=1.75\baselineskip]{geometry}

%% Paragraph settings
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\vspace{-3\parskip}\SingleSpacing}
\DoubleSpacing
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{2em}
\RaggedRight



\title{Dummy title}
\author{Dummy author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam imperdiet venenatis mi ut vehicula. Sed semper pharetra fringilla. Pellentesque scelerisque sagittis sem, ut vestibulum lectus suscipit iaculis. Proin sit amet ligula scelerisque, convallis ante et, mattis mauris. 

Praesent in viverra nulla. In eleifend posuere enim, non pharetra magna accumsan nec. Donec ullamcorper et justo imperdiet vehicula. Sed malesuada erat auctor, commodo enim vehicula, iaculis orci. 

\section
Praesent in viverra nulla. In eleifend posuere enim, non pharetra magna accumsan nec. Donec ullamcorper et justo imperdiet vehicula. Sed malesuada erat auctor, commodo enim vehicula, iaculis orci. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please complete the [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). If I add `\section` with some text, then the first paragraph is *not* indented.

Comment: Thanks! I altered the question a bit so that it addresses your answer.

Comment: `\section` is missing the argument, it takes the first following token `P`. But the paragraph is *not* indented. Do you mean the paragraph after `\maketitle`? `\maketitle` is not a `\section` command. Just add `\noindent` before the paragraph to override `\parindent` from `\RaggedRight`.

Comment: OK thanks, @HeikoOberdiek, I still have a lot to learn with Latex. Sorry for the simplistic question—I assumed the very first paragraph in a document (yes, that's what I mean; it's the same with or without a `\maketitle` command—no indent) was treated the same as a paragraph after a `\section` command. Obviously, I should not have made that assumption.

Answer (score 6):

LaTeX suppresses the indentation of the first paragraph after `\section` and friends (BTW, package `indentfirst` changes this behavior). `\maketitle` does not contain `\section` or similar commands. Therefore the paragraph after `\maketitle` is an ordinary paragraph with indentation. Command `\noindent` starts a paragraph without indentation:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,article,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[latin]{babel} % better hyphenation for "Lorem ipsum ..."

\usepackage{ragged2e}

%% Paragraph settings
\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\vspace{-3\parskip}\Single
\DoubleSpacing
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{2em}
\RaggedRight

\title{Dummy title}
\author{Dummy author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam imperdiet
venenatis mi ut vehicula. Sed semper pharetra fringilla. Pellentesque
scelerisque sagittis sem, ut vestibulum lectus suscipit iaculis. Proin sit
amet ligula scelerisque, convallis ante et, mattis mauris.

Praesent in viverra nulla. In eleifend posuere enim, non pharetra magna
accumsan nec. Donec ullamcorper et justo imperdiet vehicula. Sed malesuada
erat auctor, commodo enim vehicula, iaculis orci.

\section{Section title}
Praesent in viverra nulla. In eleifend posuere enim, non pharetra magna
accumsan nec. Donec ullamcorper et justo imperdiet vehicula. Sed malesuada
erat auctor, commodo enim vehicula, iaculis orci.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]